# Function Overloading in C++ and Data Type of Numbers

Tags: c++, overloading

When function overloading is used to which function do they actually go..?

```
void print(int);  //print 1 
void print(char *);  //print 2
void set (int *);  //set 1
void set (const char *);  //set 2
int main() {
print (0); //Which print?
set (0); //Which set?
```

And what is the type of `2`..? Is it `int` or `short`... For eg... in the following code  which f is called.. for `f(2)`

```
void f(int, double = 0.0); //f1
void f(short); //f2
```

Comment: If it's ambiguous, it won't compile.  And in the case of "set", I'm pretty sure it's ambiguous.  Did you try compiling it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> print (0); //Which print?

`print(int)` because `0` is `int`. That is an exact match — no conversion required.

> set (0); //Which set

Ambiguous, because `0` (which is `int`) can *convert* into null pointer of any type. So this code would result in compilation error.

> And what is the type of 2..? Is it int or short

It is `int`. All integral literals are `int` type if *it doesn't have any suffix*.

> For eg... in the following code which f is called.. for f(2)

Now you should figure it out yourself.